# find $f'(0)$, while $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sin(t)/t \,dt$

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

I have an integral: $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sin(t)/t\, dt$
And I have to found $f'(0)$

So, I know that I can look at the integrand  as at func $ g(x)=\sin(x)/x$ for $x \neq 0 $
$1$ for $x=0$ 
And the result is $1$

Is it correct to write it like this:
$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} (\int_{0}^{x} \sin(t)/t\, dt - \int_{0}^{0} \sin(t)/t \,dt)/(x-0)$ ,
and from L'Hospital rule:
$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)/x =1$

My Questions:
I'm not sure if I can use $\int_{0}^{0} \sin(t)/t\, dt=0$ , because the integrand isn't defined at $x=0$

Comment: How did you use l'Hopital's rule? How could you differentiate the numerator when the derivative of the numerator is basically what you're asked to find in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, you are right!

Answer (score 5):

The value of the integral doesn't change if you change the integrand at a single point, so you can assume the integrand is $$f(t)=\cases{\sin t/t ,&$t\neq0$\\1,&$t=0$}$$ and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: +1 for the simple approach based on FTC.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\left(\int\limits_0^x\frac{\sin{t}}{t}dt\right)'=\frac{\sin{x}}{x},$$ it's just $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$.

Comment: I think you should preface this with an explicit invocation of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I thought that it's obvious. I fixed.Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It's obvious to me and you and Ethan. But since this question has been posted here, it's also clear to me that it's not obviuous to the asker. And I still think you should name the theorem you're using (again, since it's clearly not entirely obvious to the asker).

Comment: I'm familiar with this theorem. The problem is, as Arthur mentioned, that I used l'hopital assuming, that I can derivative f(x) , while I have to prove it!

Comment: @Alex ˢᵅˢʰᵅ Druzina I think, now you know how to solve it. The Hospital's  rule is not necessary here. Good luck!

Comment: @AlexˢᵅˢʰᵅDruzina I think (and so do other people) that L'Hopital should be a last resort, not the first thought, when trying to solve limit problems that look indetereminate. There are usually more instructive methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to $f(x)$ you will get that $f'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and from there you take the limit in the answer by Michael.

Answer (score 0):

You do not explicitly mention where $f(x)$ is defined, but let us consider it as a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

The first question is whether $f(x)$ is well-defined, that is, whether $\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$ exists. You correctly say it is the same as
$$\int_0^x g(t)dt$$
with $g(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{\sin x}{x} & x \ne 0 \\ 
1 & x = 0
\end{cases} \quad.$
But $g$ is continuous. This is obviuos in all $x \ne 0$. In $x = 0$ it follows from $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x -\sin 0}{x - 0} = \sin'(0) = cos 0 = 1$.

Hence $f(x)$ is well-defined and the fundamental theorem of calculus implies that $f$ is differentiable with $f' = g$. Hence $f'(0) = g(0) = 1$.